# OPENERP error after logging

Tags: odoo

Hello I have OpenERP version 7. This application are installed on Centos 6.4 x64 and used PosgtreSQL and this db are installed on cluster. When I try login into I see this error:

[image]

This is error from OpenERP log file:

```
 2014-05-28 12:52:33,245 25598 INFO openerp_preprod werkzeug: 192.168.178.220 - - [28/May/2014 12:52:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 2014-05-28 12:52:33,366 25598 INFO openerp_preprod werkzeug: 192.168.175.155 - - [28/May/2014 12:52:33] "POST /web/menu/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 2014-05-28 12:52:33,785 25598 INFO openerp_preprod werkzeug: 192.168.175.155 - - [28/May/2014 12:52:33] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 2014-05-28 12:52:33,986 25598 INFO openerp_preprod werkzeug: 192.168.175.155 - - [28/May/2014 12:52:33] "POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 2014-05-28 12:52:34,121 25598 ERROR openerp_preprod openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval u"action= self.open_my_pref(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids', []), context=context)"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 289, in safe_eval
   return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
 File "", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'res.users' object has no attribute 'open_my_pref'
 2014-05-28 12:52:34,125 25598 ERROR openerp_preprod openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
   return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 611, in run
eval(action.code.strip(), cxt, mode="exec", nocopy=True) # nocopy allows to return 'action'
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 289, in safe_eval
  return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
File "", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'res.users' object has no attribute 'open_my_pref'
2014-05-28 12:52:34,125 25598 ERROR openerp_preprod openerp.netsvc: 'res.users' object has no attribute 'open_my_pref'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 297, in dispatch_rpc
  result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
res = fn(db, uid, *params)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
  return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
  return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
 return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 611, in run
eval(action.code.strip(), cxt, mode="exec", nocopy=True) # nocopy allows to return 'action'
File "/opt/openerp/openerp-sr-test/current/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 289, in safe_eval
  return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
File "", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'res.users' object has no attribute 'open_my_pref'
```

Please give me some advice what's wrong? After

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have already solved this issue but for the others..

Your code in somewhere in xml refers to a field `open_my_pref` but OpenERP / Odoo can't find it in python, or in some cases vice versa. If the field `open_my_pref` is not already defined in the code edit your code accordingly. If defined, update the module which defines it from the Settings page or run OpenERP with the following flags. `-u <module_name> -d <database_name>`